# Base url not work in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

I used the link to get the css file in my app.blade.php file is as below:-

```
<link href="{{asset('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
```

But when i inspect element have been done , the link can be shown https://localhos:8000/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css which is correct path of that file but it can not work to get the css form that file.

So please help to solve out this problem I am gladful if anyone can solve this problem.

Comment: The path to the file is correct, but the web server is returning a 404?

Comment: are you sure the file is under public dir and not resources dir?

Comment: asset() method generates links to assets that are in public directory, not in /resources/assets

Comment: Yes, I put it inside the public folder.

Comment: You're missing the **t** at the end of "localhost". Is that typo in your question or in your config?

Comment: check your file permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try without the 'assets' word in the path

```
<link href="{{asset('/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify if your file in path `/public/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css`

try this instead

```
{!! HTML::style('/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css') !!}
```